# checking the contents of a text file against a List<string>

Tags: c#, list, filereader

So, I am trying to check the contents of a text file to see if any of the values contained within the List `textwords` exist within the text file.

However when the code is executed it always thinks the message doesn't contain any of the strings contained within the `textwords` List.

The code used is below.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
List<string> textwords = new List<string>();
        using (var UnacceptableWords = new StreamReader("fileLocation"))
        {
            while (!UnacceptableWords.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] row = UnacceptableWords.ReadLine().Split(',');
                string Column1 = row[0];

                textwords.Add(Column1);
            }
        }

        directory = new DirectoryInfo("filelocation");
        files = directory.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            using(StreamReader Message = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
            {
                string MessageContents = Message.ReadToEnd();
                if(MessageContents.Contains(textwords.ToString()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("found a word");
                }
                MessageBox.Show("message clean");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `string.Cointains()` method takes in a string but you are passing into it the `List`, which you have turned into a string.

**List.ToString() != Values contained in the List as strings**

To do this you must iterate through the array and pass each element of it at a time

```
foreach(string keyword in textwords)
{
    if(MessageContents.Contains(keyword))
    {
         MessageBox.Show("found a word");
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, you are making the same mistake as in the original question. Only that you are doing it multiple times. The test should be `if (MessageContents.Contains(keyword))`

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake, I copied the if and forgot to change it, will edit now.
Thanks for pointing it out, that was my original intention

Comment: Wouldnt Linq be able to do this?

Comment: @BenKnoble Linq would definitely be an option, but I am not particularly well versed in it and would not be able to give a definite solution using it, feel free to answer yourself :)

Comment: @bdg have you changed it to use `keyword` in the contains instead of the list?

Comment: Also consider that `Contains` respects casing. So `"TheQuickBrownFox".Contains("fox")` returns `false`!

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake it does in fact work, I hadnt gone through all the words Thanks for your help!